# How to use output_inhibited?

Tags: origen-sdk

We don't use Flow_global.aiv or Flow_global.pmfl. I was wondering how to set `inhibit_output` on a per generator basis from our interface so that these files are not generated by default.

Comment: fyi I've figured out a workaround for now, in our interface shutdown I've added:
pattern_masters.delete('global')
pattern_compilers.delete('global')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work from your interface:

```
pattern_master.inhibit_output
pattern_compiler.inhibit_output
```

e.g. in an [`on_flow_start`](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/#on_flow_start(options)) callback